# Why does semicolon take 500x longer to execute than a comma?

Tags: powershell

Consider the following PowerShell code:

```
$sw = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$sw.Start()
$sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;$sw.elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
```

Output:

```
32351.1651
32352.839
```

It seems that it takes between 1 and 2 milliseconds for a semicolon to execute.

However, when swapped for a much smaller comma, the times go down significantly:

```
$sw2 = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$sw2.Start()
$sw2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds,$sw2.elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
```

Output:

```
21106.2669
21106.272
```

Comma can run in just around 6-8 microseconds; that's like more than two orders of magnitude faster!

Is this because of its size? Or agility? Obviously, as a smaller punctuation mark, a comma consumes less RAM but this does not explain such a huge difference.

Any ideas?

My enviromnent: Windows 7 Enterprise x64, PowerShell 6.2, 3.4 GHz i7 CPU.

Comment: Microbenchmarks like these are fraud with something as high level as PowerShell; a single stray thread pre-emption can change the values considerably. The humorous tone of your question notwithstanding, if you wanted to be serious about timing this you'd need many, many more cycles and average out the results. Even then, ultimately the answer would lie in profiling the code. Semantically, `a;b` and `a,b` are not at all the same thing; the former is two commands, the latter one. It stands to reason the execution of a command has a big chunk of overhead.

Comment: I actually ran this code many, many times in a loop and the averages check out. If the latter is a single instruction then why time difference at all?

Comment: Neither the comma nor that semi-colon are "executing", but they do have an impact on how (and, more importantly, _when_) the two value expression are executed - in the first case as _two separate statements_, in the latter immediately after eachother as part of the same binary operation.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't get at all comparable results on my Win10 machine with PowerShell 5.1, but of course the code base for that is completely different.

Comment: And I don't understand "why the time difference at all" -- they're *different things*, so they'll take a different amount of time, just because PowerShell is doing something different. I sincerely doubt much effort has already been spent on profiling and optimizing execution paths in PowerShell Core, as opposed to adding new features and cmdlets!

Comment: The humorous tone was sort of spontaneous. I am well aware that a comma cannot consume 1/500 RAM of what a semicolon does ;) But still, I am curious why there is a difference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in evaluation.

---

```
$a, $b
```

This is creating an array; a single result (`object[]` or `T[]`) comes out of it.

---

```
$a; $b
```

This is executing two different statements, and two different objects are output to the console (which also has its slowness compared to doing things in memory) and is equivalent to doing

```
$a
$b
```

---

Ultimately, I believe the large difference you're observing is due to printing one object vs. multiple objects to the console.

Answer (score 2):

TheIncorrigible is spot on, but I thought trying to illustrate the resulting expression tree of your two examples might help explain why the first delta is much longer that the next.

This is roughly the expression tree generated by PowerShell for the first case (separating the expressions with semi-colon `;`)

```
                       Block ($a.b.c;$a.b.c)
                       /   \
          ____________/     \____________
          | pipeline |       | pipeline |
               /                   \
   ___________/________     ________\_________
  { expression: $a.b.c }   { expression: $a.b.c }
```

PowerShell sees the `;` and treats the two expressions each as the starting element of a separate pipeline. So after evaluating the first expression, and obtaining the value of `$a.b.c`, before the runtime can evaluate the second expression it needs to "wrap up" the parent pipeline, including outputting the resulting value.

In the second case, however, the resulting expression tree looks a bit different

```
                       Block ($a.b.c,$a.b.c)
                         |
                   ______|______
                   | pipeline  |
                         |
                   ______|______
                   |  array op |
   ________________|___     ___|________________
  { expression: $a.b.c }   { expression: $a.b.c }
```

Here, both expressions are evaluated immediately after each other, as part the binary array operation represented by `,` - in other words, the runtime doesn't have anything else it needs to do in between evaluating the two expressions, and therefore the time delta is extremely small.

I hope this helps shed some light on the discrepancy

---

> Obviously, as a smaller punctuation mark, a comma consumes less RAM but this does not explain such a huge difference

## This is nonsense

`,` and `;` needs the exact same amount of memory allocated - 2 bytes